# Python openpyxl fails to save existing excel having customized column width

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm generating one Excel with a template,

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

src_file = 'D:\\code\\TestLink-Report\\pyxl.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(filename = src_file, guess_types = False)

sheet = wb.worksheets[0]
sheet.cell('A1').value = 'blabla'
wb.save(filename =  src_file)
```

If src_file is new blank one, it works.
If I change width of any column in src file by manual, run code again, it fails

```
    wb.save(filename =  src_file)
  File "D:\Python27\envs\TestLink\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook.py", line 265, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "D:\Python27\envs\TestLink\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line
 187, in save_workbook
    writer.save(filename)
  File "D:\Python27\envs\TestLink\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line
 170, in save
    self.write_data(archive)
  File "D:\Python27\envs\TestLink\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line
 98, in write_data
    self._write_worksheets(archive, shared_string_table, self.style_writer)
  File "D:\Python27\envs\TestLink\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line
 128, in _write_worksheets
    style_writer.get_style_by_hash()))
  File "D:\Python27\envs\TestLink\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\worksheet.py", line 98, in write_worksheet
    write_worksheet_cols(doc, worksheet, style_table)
  File "D:\Python27\envs\TestLink\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\worksheet.py", line 209, in write_worksheet_cols
    col_def['style'] = str(style_table[hash(columndimension.style_index)])
KeyError: 549131827
```

I'm using Excel 2013.
I heard openpyxl doesn't support style well after searching on stackoverflow. But my problem seems that it should be one simple thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved [here](https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/issue/258/missing-value-in-style_table-on-saving-a)

run this to get the latest version

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl
cd openpyxl/
hg up 1.8
python setup.py develop
```

Comment: openpyxl was 1.x when I asked this question. Now it's 2.x and works well. Validated with 2.4.7 version.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use **`win32com`** as an option? A simple column formatting can be done there like below:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

xl = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
filestr = "C:\blah\pytest.xlsx"
wbk = xl.Workbooks.Open(filestr)

wsht = wbk.Sheets(1)
wsht.Range("A1").Value = "Hello World!"
wsht.Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 50
wbk.SaveAs("C:\blah\pytested.xlsx")

xl.Application.Quit()
```

You can use it in conjunction with **`openpyxl`** if you just need to adjust column widths.

Let us know if this helps. :)

Comment: I has been dislike 'Excel.Application' but seems no better choice. I thought I had one awesome solution without OLE automation.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently work going on in `openpyxl` to resolve the error you're getting. Both the 1.8 and 1.9 branches will currently prevent it happening but the resulting Excel files may not be usable.

Comment: Great! Look forward to the release.